# Is it possible for a person to live off a special drink that provides him all required nutrients that his body need?

Tags: food

Due to a unique condition, a man is in a malnourished state where he already lost almost all of his muscles and fat, leaving him barely able to walk around his house before dropping to the ground exhausted. The man doesn't know why, but he can't eat much food, as his body forces him to feel full, even though he knows it's far from enough.

But thankfully, at least he has that special drink.

I don't know much about things like this, as I only possess somewhat surface knowledge. So I wanted to ask about your opinions.

Comment: "special drink that contains all the essentials his body needed to survive " - why would you question that that person couldn't live off this? What is it lacking that normal food contains, or has that normal food doesn't? There might well be a problem with the jaw muscles atrophying, and the teeth losing their accourage as the bone recedes, but what are you asking? Could you clarify what the worldbuilding problem is, what's the context? At the moment this doesn't seem to be more than a medical/nutrition problem, not a worldbuilding one.

Comment: Due to a unique condition, man is in a malnourished state where he already lost almost all of his muscles and fat leaving him barely able to walk around his house before dropping on ground exhausted. Even man don't know how but he coudn't eat much food to live as his body forcing him to feel full depite he know its far from enought.

Comment: In the title you are asking a question which is different from what you are asking in the body. Which of the two is your question?

Comment: it is a later one.

Comment: liquid diets already exist, see people who have their jaws wired shut. the most important thing is they need to eat about twice as much because water adds so much bulk lowering the caloric content.

Comment: Honestly, if you wanted, you could just create a fictional drink that did all that, without explaining why it works. It is called 'fiction' for a reason.

Comment: this is trivially answered with yes, since you specify that the drink provides all he needs. the better question would be, why this drink doesn't trigger his feeling of satiation.

Comment: Soylent is such a drink, or at least tries to be. But it does feel like a creamy meal instead of a thirst quencher.

Answer (score 5):

It depends by what you mean by "a drink". If you mean a drink resembling water with dissolved nutrients in it then no. If you mean a drink that is denser (thicker), something resembling a thick shake, or thicker, then maybe. It depends on what the drink contains.

The drink would need to contain vitamins, minerals, protein, lipids (oils and fats), carbohydrates and fiber.The fiber is where the density of the drink can be affected.

In providing nutrition to the person you also need to provide nutrition to the microbes within the digestive system to ensure a healthy [brain-gut connection](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/wellness-and-prevention/the-brain-gut-connection). As part of the requirement for this, you need fiber. Fiber is also required for a healthy bowel and intestines.

Comment: You have basically summed it up, I would suggest that if their malnourished state leaves them finding it hard to swallow thick shakes, then amino acid drinks which are more like a dilute squash plus a carb drink of the same fashion can help until they can stomach the thicker stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The magic phrase you probably should be searching for is [Medical Food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_food) (or alternatively, [Foods for Special Medical Purposes](https://bsna.co.uk/pages/about-specialist-nutrition/medical-oral-nutritional-supplements)). A nutritionally complete medical food could indeed fit your requirements. [Here's an example commercial product](https://abbottnutrition.com/vital-hp) (no affiliation). In some cases you can deliver this stuff via a [nasogastric tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasogastric_intubation) if there are eg. issues swallowing.

It is also possible to feed someone via an intravenous line in the form of [total parenteral nutrition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenteral_nutrition) which can overcome a whole bunch of difficulties in eating, digesting or absorbing nutrients, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It exists:

https://www.nestlenutritionstore.com/vivonexr-plus.html

Nutritionally complete, liquid.  Very digestible, free of **most** allergy triggers.  Surprisingly, you tend to adapt to the bad taste pretty quickly.  (Note that their mixing directions produce a much worse taste than need be.  Use a one of those sports shaker bottles, mix with room temperature water and then put it in the fridge until chilled, drink directly from the bottle.)

However, I don't know how much of a solution this will be--it's no less filling than a normal meal, although given it's rapid digestion you would be able to eat more often.

Comment: There are a whole bunch of these. I believe they're generally called "meal replacement shakes." (The one I sometimes drink tastes like chocolate milk.)

Comment: you couldn't pay me to get anything Nestle at the moment

Comment: @ITAlex If you need what I linked to you don't really have a choice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can survive on just a drink. I would suggest just blended raw eggs.

Egg whites contain a lot of protein. Egg yolks contain a lot of fat.

You can buy pre-blended egg whites and egg yolks (already separated) so you can control the proportions of protein and fat. You can also add a multivitamins in a finely powdered form, and other oils if you like.

Carbohydrates are NOT an essential dietary element. That is what the Atkins diet is all about. Without carbs, the body will go into dietary ketosis, which is not dangerous. Ketosis is the state in which our cells live on "ketones", produced by the liver from proteins and fats.

All cells have two separate energy pathways; one using carbs and one using ketones, the latter is typically so the body can live off its fat in times of famine. By not eating any carbs, the body enters this state of ketosis instead, and can survive indefinitely on just protein and fats.

That said, if you really want some carbs, add honey to the blend. There will be no fiber, but that is also not a dietary essential.

If you want to prevent cravings, you should add a dose of salt and calcium. Although egg yolks contain about 50mg of calcium, the RDA is 1200 mg. That could be provided by 3 antacid tablets like Tums.

Of course if you insist upon some vegetable components, many can be grated, dried and powdered, pressed or juiced to provide nutrients or carbohydrates. Beans, for example, can be cooked soft enough to make a paste, which in turn can be blended with liquids to make them drinkable. They may act as a thickener, of course.

So yes, one can easily drink all the required nutrients a body needs; I haven't worked out all the RDA recommendations, but it is clearly plausible such a drink can exist.

Comment: Carbohydrates are necessary, that is why keto and atkins are short term diets that most doctors would not advise. Ketosis is beneficial and best achieved through intermittent fasting.

Comment: @JarredJones That is false. Carbohydrates are **not** necessary, they are not classified as **essential nutrients** anywhere. Catch up on your medical science: https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article/75/5/951/4689417?login=false There are no long term symptoms of eliminating carbohydrates from the diet. Vitamin supplements are likely necessary, but I have specified that; there are several vitamins usually consumed with plants, a deficiency can develop, but these vitamins themselves are not carbohydrates.